# Problem Defining Header on useSubmit hook on Remix 1.15

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, remix.run

I am sending a POST request using `useSubmit` hook for it but it seems that the header that I define is not taken in consideration.

Here is my submit:

```
  submit('/dashboard/', {
     method: 'post',
     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({ some: "values" }),
  });
```

Here is my action function:

```
export async function action({ request }) {
  console.log('request: ', request);
  const data = await request.json();
  return "uhuu";
}
```

And here is the log of the request received on the action function. Observe on the header the content-type
[image]

Observe that it is not what I defined on

```js
submit('/dashboard/', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
```

I'm running it from localhost:3000

Using Postman it worked fine the problem is when I try to use the `useSubmit` on the code, the `"Content-Type"` on the header changed correctly to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.

Comment: Please do [edit] to include more actual code snippets instead of images of text/code. Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable. See [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, all of Remix data mutation API: `useSubmit`, `fetcher.submit`, etc will always send the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is how the browser does form POST.

However, there's an active PR that will allow you to override this behavior and let you specify the encoding type.

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/10324

In the meantime, the general "solution" is to specify a single FormData value and stringify the JSON value.

```js
submit({json: JSON.stringify(obj)}, { method: 'POST' })

// action
const formData = await request.formData()
const data = JSON.parse(formData.get('json'))
```